# Overloading operators with the IndexerName attribute

Tags: c#, overloading, indexer

I am wondering whether it is allowed in C# to provide the `IndexerName` attribute defining the same name for overloaded indexers which have the same semantics. Say, for example, that you have a wrapper class for matrices of unknown size which defines two indexers, one for `Int32` and one for `Int64` array access:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class Matrix
{
    private double[,] content;

    [IndexerName("Cells")]
    public double this[int row, int column]
    {
        get { return this.content[row, column]; }
        set { this.content[row, column] = value; }
    }

    [IndexerName("Cells")]
    public double this[long row, long column]
    {
        get { return this.content[row, column]; }
        set { this.content[row, column] = value; }
    }
}
```

So obviously, the indexers do not differ in their semantics, but in their arguments. The code will not compile, as now, the `Matrix` type already contains a definition for 'Cells'. Is it even valid to use the `IndexerName` attribute in this situtation or do I have a wrong understanding of this attribute?

Comment: That does compile.  http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:s/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsB0AlYFljqqYDCA9ugA5gA2qATnAwG5gDGqIA3AFA+XAARjXYw2NAIYgQMALITk9MAA8eAbx4wtMSkuYLUMACZkhdANoAaALpiy+VPl6bt5gJIQjqZQwByEogAKACISVBoaEGCASmsXLQFhURMzQ2QACzAQc0hkGHoyAHdLGFy7GmB0CDjtGA1a2qhUPLV85uB6CBgMrMw2ezR8cwLi8srqrhgAX3iGkGa67syQPoHHZGGikv6KqtsAXhh9CtRJmdqZ2fdPbz8A1BCwiKjY2cSRNmNTYTTl8xp7LARiUAdAxntZvUGlomi02sgOl0eit+g4hsDwRNprNavM4cjVmiNhiduMDkcJCczrMZlMgAA

Comment: `IndexerName` is a hint for compiler writers, incidentally mentioned in the documentation. It does not actually do anything. C# does not use it either.

Comment: @SLaks you are absolutely right. In my actual code, the indexer name coincided with a member of the class which I removed by narrowing it down to a minimal example.

Comment: Please be clear about what problem it is _exactly_ that you are trying to solve. Show the context, how you expect to use this attribute, why you think it would or should solve the problem, and explain clearly in what way it's not working for you.